# Android AEE/AED fatal error

Tags: android, kernel

How to analysis the root cause of android aee/aed error? Can you give me any point to analysis of this. thanks.

```
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : ----- pid 5515 at 2015-01-01 00:13:43 -----
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Cmd line: com.android.settings
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : ABI: arm64
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Build type: optimized
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Zygote loaded classes=3706 post zygote classes=611
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Intern table: 55010 strong; 415 weak
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : JNI: CheckJNI is off; globals=830
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Libraries: /system/lib64/libandroid.so /system/lib64/libaudioeffect_jni.so /system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib64/libjnigraphics.so /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib64/libmeizucamera.so /system/lib64/librs_jni.so /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so libjavacore.so (11)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Heap: 11% free, 21MB/24MB; 110877 objects
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Dumping Gc info
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Last paused time of concurrent mark sweep : 484ns
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Last paused time of sticky concurrent mark sweep : 432ns
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Last paused time of marksweep + semispace : 31.121us
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Total number of allocations: 686974
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : Total bytes allocated 56MB
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : 
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : DALVIK THREADS (25):
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x75ec5c70 self=0x7f7d49a000
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   | sysTid=5515 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f81503eb0
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   | state=S schedstat=( 7412755439 806326100 5820 ) utm=699 stm=42 core=1 HZ=100
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   | stack=0x7ff0a51000-0x7ff0a53000 stackSize=8MB
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   | held mutexes=
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/5515/stack)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   native: #00 pc 00062b00  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   native: #01 pc 00089108  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+96)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   native: #02 pc 0002993c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+164)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   native: #03 pc 0002a394  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+116)
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED :   native: #04 pc 0002a600  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadSta
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 I AEE/AED : $** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Fatal *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **$
01-01 00:14:40.348  7087  7087 D AEE/AED : aed_report_dumpstate: filepath /sdcard/mtklog/aee_exp/temp/db.6rpuAh, pid 979, tid -1361051648, exp_class 5, db_opt 0
```

I want to know  if the above is an error？ And how to detail which function is the root cause?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AEE/AED is developed by Mediatek, not a general Android module.

Comment: so can you describe the problem for this log?

Comment: when dismissing keyguard to login in to phone desktop, it caused black screen.